# android doesn't show gif

Tags: java, android, gif

I'm new in android development, so I have the following issue. I'm trying to show gif green.gif (res/drawable-xxhdpi/) via this code:
GIFView class:

```
package ru.rkarasev.miptrain;

import java.io.InputStream;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Movie;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class GIFView extends View {
    private Movie movie;
    private InputStream is;
    private long moviestart;

    public GIFView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        is = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.green);
        movie = Movie.decodeStream(is);
    }

    public GIFView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        is = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.green);
        movie = Movie.decodeStream(is);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        long now = android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

        if (moviestart == 0)
            moviestart = now;

        int relTime = (int) ((now - moviestart) % movie.duration());
        movie.setTime(relTime);
        movie.draw(canvas, 100, 100);
        this.invalidate();
    }
}
```

XML file part:

```
<TableRow>
     <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/final_1"
        android:width="200dp"
        android:textSize="25sp"/>
      <ru.rkarasev.miptrain.GIFView
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/greenarrow">
        </ru.rkarasev.miptrain.GIFView>

     <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/time_1"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="30sp"/>
</TableRow>
```

Activity code:

```
GIFView gifview = (GIFView) findViewById(R.id.greenarrow);
```

But the space where this view should be is empty, it doesn't show anything! Could you tell me what's the problem?

UPD: When I open activity_main.xml file, it doesn't show how my layout will look but give me this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ru.rkarasev.miptrain.GIFView.onDraw(GIFView.java:34)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13707)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13591)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2928)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2797)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13589)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2928)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2797)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13589)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2928)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2797)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13710)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13591)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2928)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2797)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13589)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2928)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2797)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13710)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13591)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2928)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2797)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13710)
```

34th string in GIFView is:

```
int relTime = (int)((now - moviestart) % movie.duration());
```

It seems like there was no movie initialized, but why?

If I also add

```
System.out.println(movie.duration());
```

in the beginning of onDraw method, it gives me 2100ms, which is correct value. It eludes me at all.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your Movie object is null, and after tracing the source code of [Movie Class](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3_r1/android/graphics/Movie.java#Movie.decodeStream%28java.io.InputStream%29) it fails silently (by catching the thrown IOException) and returns a null object.

just add a null check in your code and try to decode the gif file in another way. take a look here :

[Failed to decode GIF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088865/failed-to-decode-some-animated-gif-files-using-movie-on-android-2-3-x-or-lower)

or you could try to move your GIF to the assets folder as suggested here :[SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7777315/showing-gif-in-android)

Comment: move to the assets folder? What does it mean?

Comment: move your gif from project-base/res/drawable to project-base/assets/

Comment: if his Movie object were null, how could he get the duration of it without throwing a NullPointerException?

Comment: he says it throws NullPointerException in the oDraw method so I guess duration() caused it