# Display GIF image from URL in android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to design an app and all I want it to do is load an image from a URL.I m displaying GIF image with the URL(from internet) but it is not displaying the image.I have posted code as well as logcat below:

```
Activity

package com.example.mosdacappalert_radio;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class Heavy_rain1 extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_heavy_rain1);
        RelativeLayout myLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.addView);

        myLayout.addView(new com.example.mosdacappalert_radio.ShowGifView(this,
                "http://graphico.in/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Happy-anniversary-wishes-to-you.gif"));
    }
}


class file

package com.example.mosdacappalert_radio;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Movie;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class ShowGifView extends View {

    // Set true to use decodeStream
    // Set false to use decodeByteArray
    private static final boolean DECODE_STREAM = true;

    private InputStream gifInputStream;
    private Movie gifMovie;
    private int movieWidth, movieHeight;
    private long movieDuration;
    private long mMovieStart;

    static String gifURL;

    public ShowGifView(Context context, String a) {
        super(context);
        gifURL = a;
        init(context);
    }

    public ShowGifView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public ShowGifView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(final Context context) {
        setFocusable(true);

        gifMovie = null;
        movieWidth = 0;
        movieHeight = 0;
        movieDuration = 0;
        Loder task = new Loder();
        task.execute(new String[] { gifURL });

    }

    private static byte[] streamToBytes(InputStream is) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        try {
            while ((len = is.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
                os.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
        } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
        }
        return os.toByteArray();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        setMeasuredDimension(movieWidth, movieHeight);
    }

    public int getMovieWidth() {
        return movieWidth;
    }

    public int getMovieHeight() {
        return movieHeight;
    }

    public long getMovieDuration() {
        return movieDuration;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        long now = android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        if (mMovieStart == 0) { // first time
            mMovieStart = now;
        }

        if (gifMovie != null) {

            int dur = gifMovie.duration();
            if (dur == 0) {
                dur = 1000;
            }

            int relTime = (int) ((now - mMovieStart) % dur);

            gifMovie.setTime(relTime);

            gifMovie.draw(canvas, 0, 0);
            invalidate();

        }

    }

    private class Loder extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            URL gifURL;
            try {
                gifURL = new URL(urls[0]);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) gifURL
                        .openConnection();

                gifInputStream = connection.getInputStream();

                // Insert dummy sleep
                // to simulate network delay
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if (DECODE_STREAM) {
                    gifMovie = Movie.decodeStream(gifInputStream);
                } else {
                    byte[] array = streamToBytes(gifInputStream);
                    gifMovie = Movie.decodeByteArray(array, 0, array.length);
                }
                movieWidth = gifMovie.width();
                movieHeight = gifMovie.height();
                movieDuration = gifMovie.duration();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            invalidate();
            requestLayout();

        }
    }

}

XML

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/addView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
     >
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>


Logcat:

12-08 19:18:37.408: W/System.err(4521): java.io.IOException
12-08 19:18:37.428: W/System.err(4521):     at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.reset(InflaterInputStream.java:279)
12-08 19:18:37.428: W/System.err(4521):     at android.graphics.Movie.decodeStream(Native Method)
12-08 19:18:37.428: W/System.err(4521):     at com.example.mosdacappalert_radio.ShowGifView$Loder.doInBackground(ShowGifView.java:136)
12-08 19:18:37.428: W/System.err(4521):     at com.example.mosdacappalert_radio.ShowGifView$Loder.doInBackground(ShowGifView.java:1)
12-08 19:18:37.428: W/System.err(4521):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
12-08 19:18:37.428: W/System.err(4521):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
12-08 19:18:37.428: W/System.err(4521):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
12-08 19:18:37.438: W/System.err(4521):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
12-08 19:18:37.438: W/System.err(4521):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
12-08 19:18:37.438: W/System.err(4521):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
12-08 19:18:37.438: D/skia(4521): ------- reset threw an exception
12-08 19:18:37.438: W/System.err(4521): java.io.IOException
12-08 19:18:37.448: W/System.err(4521):     at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.reset(InflaterInputStream.java:279)
12-08 19:18:37.448: W/System.err(4521):     at android.graphics.Movie.decodeStream(Native Method)
12-08 19:18:37.448: W/System.err(4521):     at com.example.mosdacappalert_radio.ShowGifView$Loder.doInBackground(ShowGifView.java:136)
12-08 19:18:37.448: W/System.err(4521):     at com.example.mosdacappalert_radio.ShowGifView$Loder.doInBackground(ShowGifView.java:1)
12-08 19:18:37.448: W/System.err(4521):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
12-08 19:18:37.448: W/System.err(4521):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
12-08 19:18:37.448: W/System.err(4521):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
12-08 19:18:37.448: W/System.err(4521):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
12-08 19:18:37.448: W/System.err(4521):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
12-08 19:18:37.448: W/System.err(4521):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
12-08 19:18:37.448: D/skia(4521): ------- reset threw an exception
12-08 19:18:37.498: W/System.err(4521): java.io.IOException
12-08 19:18:37.518: W/System.err(4521):     at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.reset(InflaterInputStream.java:279)
12-08 19:18:37.518: W/System.err(4521):     at android.graphics.Movie.decodeStream(Native Method)
12-08 19:18:37.518: W/System.err(4521):     at com.example.mosdacappalert_radio.ShowGifView$Loder.doInBackground(ShowGifView.java:136)
12-08 19:18:37.518: W/System.err(4521):     at com.example.mosdacappalert_radio.ShowGifView$Loder.doInBackground(ShowGifView.java:1)
12-08 19:18:37.518: W/System.err(4521):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
12-08 19:18:37.518: W/System.err(4521):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
12-08 19:18:37.518: W/System.err(4521):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
12-08 19:18:37.518: W/System.err(4521):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
12-08 19:18:37.518: W/System.err(4521):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
12-08 19:18:37.518: W/System.err(4521):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
12-08 19:18:37.518: D/skia(4521): ------- reset threw an exception
12-08 19:18:37.518: W/System.err(4521): java.io.IOException
12-08 19:18:37.518: W/System.err(4521):     at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.reset(InflaterInputStream.java:279)
12-08 19:18:37.518: W/System.err(4521):     at android.graphics.Movie.decodeStream(Native Method)
12-08 19:18:37.528: W/System.err(4521):     at com.example.mosdacappalert_radio.ShowGifView$Loder.doInBackground(ShowGifView.java:136)
12-08 19:18:37.528: W/System.err(4521):     at com.example.mosdacappalert_radio.ShowGifView$Loder.doInBackground(ShowGifView.java:1)
12-08 19:18:37.528: W/System.err(4521):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
12-08 19:18:37.528: W/System.err(4521):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
12-08 19:18:37.528: W/System.err(4521):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
12-08 19:18:37.528: W/System.err(4521):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
12-08 19:18:37.528: W/System.err(4521):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
12-08 19:18:37.528: W/System.err(4521):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
12-08 19:18:37.528: D/skia(4521): ------- reset threw an exception
12-08 19:18:37.528: W/System.err(4521): java.io.IOException
12-08 19:18:37.528: W/System.err(4521):     at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.reset(InflaterInputStream.java:279)
12-08 19:18:37.528: W/System.err(4521):     at android.graphics.Movie.decodeStream(Native Method)
12-08 19:18:37.528: W/System.err(4521):     at com.example.mosdacappalert_radio.ShowGifView$Loder.doInBackground(ShowGifView.java:136)
12-08 19:18:37.528: W/System.err(4521):     at com.example.mosdacappalert_radio.ShowGifView$Loder.doInBackground(ShowGifView.java:1)
12-08 19:18:37.528: W/System.err(4521):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
12-08 19:18:37.528: W/System.err(4521):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
12-08 19:18:37.528: W/System.err(4521):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
12-08 19:18:37.528: W/System.err(4521):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
12-08 19:18:37.528: W/System.err(4521):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
12-08 19:18:37.528: W/System.err(4521):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
12-08 19:18:37.538: D/skia(4521): ------- reset threw an exception
12-08 19:18:37.538: D/skia(4521): QURAMWINKI_ParseGIFHeader_SKIA error
12-08 19:18:37.538: D/skia(4521): Wink AGIF Move Constructer End 0, totalTime : 0
12-08 19:18:37.558: D/skia(4521): Wink AGIF onGetBitmap Null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

1. **Movie** (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Movie.html)
2. **WebView** (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)

Movie class :- 
 Introduced in API level 1 of android but GIF decoding is not working for all devices. Facing in-consistence problems on some versions of some devices like on Xperia L with 2.3.3 is not working etc.

> So to avoid above issue simply go with **WebView**, just load GIF url in
>   it.

Answer (score 0):

From [this SE answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088865/failed-to-decode-some-animated-gif-files-using-movie-on-android-2-3-x-or-lower) it looks like animated GIF support using the `Movie` class is somewhat problematic (it doesn't work on older APIs and it fails on certain types of GIF encodings). Might be simpler to just use `WebView`.